# Can I create a pre-compiled tarball with Python 3.7 for AWS Linux AMI (RHEL)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, redhat

I'd like to create a tarball containing a pre-compiled version of Python 3.7 to be placed on Amazon S3.

On AWS Linux AMI based on Red-Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), I am downloading the source code and compiling Python 3.7 every time I have to initialize a new AMI.

The `yum` package manager does not seem to have a pre-compiled version of Python 3.7.

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
tar xJf Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
rm -f Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
```

The code works fine, but it takes too long to boot up.